# clustering cell tower ids

Tags: cluster-analysis, telecommunication, cellular-network

If you have a list of cell tower ids and their respective start and end time (i.e. the time the phone was registered at that tower), is there an easy to cluster the ids and visualise the cells and their clusters in a diagram?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without some knowledge of location. Minimally at start time and at end time. If you were travelling in a line for example you could estimate the distance of the tower from the midpoint of those. If you just have time data but no location data there is nothing you can map.

**Edit:** To simplify, if you have **no location data**, you can't map much of anything, you could simply index transitions - which towers are certainly adjacent. If you jumped from tower A to B to D to B to C to F to C to D to E to A, then you can map them in graph form:

```
A -- B -- C -- F
|    | //
E -- D
```

This is only the connections that are *definitely* there, in the example F could be connected to D, or B could be connected to E, but you can only map the transitions you are sure of.

With **location data for the mobile device**, you could map the *points of influence* of the towers. From these points you could derive probable areas of influence (circular).

Conversely with **location data for the towers**, you could map probable transition spots. These could be connected into polygons of influence.

With no location data you can only make speculative graphs.

Comment: My data are in the following format: 1071.8232365, Fri Mar 18 09:30:14 GMT 2011, Fri Mar 18 09:30:31 GMT 2011
The first value is the areaid.towerid and the other two, is span the mobile was in that location.

Comment: what if you had gps location together with these? however, the gps location would not be as accurate.